# Drawing Candlestick and volume chart using Matplotlib's bar chart with skip weekend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stock, candlestick-chart

As I was trying to print out a stock candlestick chart using Matplotlib, I noticed they've moved their candlestick_ohlc to another library (mpl_finance) that should be installed and imported separately. As I didn't want to do that, I thought of sharing how to do it with the standard Matplotlib's library as I saw most guides on the internet are rather old and using that separate library. So if you want, you can suggest ways to improve this code too (this code skips weekends too):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = df.sort_values(by=['trade_date'], ascending=True)
N = len(dsh_sorted['trade_date']) 
ind = np.arange(N)
# A function to remove weekends 
def format_date(x, pos=None): # x counts for all ticks, pos counts for the visible ticks.
    thisind = np.clip(int(x), 0, N-1)
    if x<0 or x>(N-1): #There are one more x on each side of data range to have spaces from the chart edge
        date_string=""
    else:
        date_string = df.iloc[thisind , df.columns.get_loc('trade_date')].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return date_string
df['candle_height'] = df["close"]-df["open"]
candle_chart = ax.bar(x=ind, height = df.candle_height.abs(), bottom = df[["open", "close"]].min(axis=1),
                       yerr=[df[["open", "close"]].max(axis=1)-df["min"],df["max"]-df[["open", "close"]].max(axis=1)], 
                       color = ['green' if i>=0 else 'red' for i in df['candle_height']],
                       ecolor= ['green' if i>=0 else 'red' for i in df['candle_height']], 
                       width=0.25, label=[], alpha=1, error_kw={'alpha':0.8})
#Now to put the volume chart bellow the candlestick chart
ax_vol=ax.twinx()
vol_chart = ax_vol.bar(ind, df['volume'], width=0.25, color=('blue'), label=[])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
#Although candlestick chart is obvious and might not need a legend, I put this here as help on how to add a combined legend to a matplotlib's plot manually.
ax_legend = plt.legend(handles=[candle_chart, vol_chart], labels=['Prices', 'Volumes'], loc='best', framealpha=0.6)
plt.gca().add_artist(ax_legend)
ax_vol.set_ylim(0,3*df['volume'].max())    #it kinda squishes down the volume scale
ax_vol.grid(False)    #if you don't do this, the y grids of both charts will be mixed in a not pretty way
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: To make a graph only for weekdays, you need to aggregate it with `df['drade_date’].resample('B')`.

Comment: @r-beginners Well, my  DF was already in day format, but I wasn't aware of this function and was very interesting to know. Makes creating weekly or monthly charts quite easy.